# Cannot add custom screen resolution in Ubuntu Gnome (yet working on Unity and KDE Neon)

Tags: unity, gnome, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have recently followed the steps in this [tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) to add a custom screen resolution to my Ubuntu system. It has all worked and by typing `xrandr` we see that the new screen resolution has been successfully added:

[image]

However, I have updated yesterday to Ubuntu 17.10 and Gnome came installed as default (along with Unity). When I tried to add the screen resolution 1600x900 in Gnome, I have already noticed a weird screen name (XWAYLANDO) as shown below:

[image]

One can also notice that, unlike in Unity, not all the screen resolutions are displayed here.

When I then try to add the screen resolution, I get the following error message:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on/ how can I solve this? I also managed to add the same custom screen resolution on KDE Neon (which is installed completely independent from Unity/ Gnome, on another partition of my computer).

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back from Wayland to Xorg, as described at [How to Switch to Xorg from Wayland in Ubuntu 17.10  | itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/) And after reboot the previous settings, described in the tutorial you mentioned, worked as usual.

In Ubuntu 17.10, restart your system. At the login screen, under the password field, you’ll see a gear icon. Just click on it and you’ll see two options here.

[image: Ubuntu 17.10 login screen]

The default Ubuntu means it will be using Wayland while Ubuntu on Xorg obviously means it will use Xorg. You can select Ubuntu on Xorg to use Xorg here.